# Common Cisco Firewall SNMP performance counters

Tags: cisco-asa, monitoring, snmp

I'm looking for Cisco OIDs for monitoring Cisco ASA series. Is the CISCO-UNIFIED-FIREWALL-MIB enough? What are the statistics and status indicators I should gather?

I'm interested in :

- Resource consumption (CPU utilization/memory usage)
- Current Active Connections
- Active VPN Tunnels - Items: AnyConnect (SSL client), WebVPN (SSL clientless), IPsec, IPsec L2L, etc.
- RAS Sessions (Total)
- Traffic in/out (packets/bytes)
- IKE Dropped Packets
- IKE Traffic (bits/sec)

Comment: Quite open ended question, but I'd certainly always for all firewalls poll session count and set up alarm long before hitting limit.

Comment: @JohnTube, if you can limit the scope of the question to monitoring a class of events (such as drops for out of sequence packets), or measuring a specific subsystem (such as cpu utilization of each cpu core) we can consider reopening... at this point, we don't know enough about the environment to do anything more than give you a generic list of OIDs that we personally like... a fair question on other discussion boards, but stack exchange looks for specific material in questions

Comment: Are you only interested in SNMP, or will CLI counters be useful too?

Comment: SNMP only. Preferably objects must not be table entries nor traps/notifications. I'm limited to a 3rd party NMS.